# How do I add entries to Windows Explorer's "Other Places" sidebar?

Tags: windows-xp, windows-explorer

In Windows XP the Windows Explorer has a "common tasks" sidebar on the left hand side of the Explorer window that shows grouped items based on the part of the file system being explored. When viewing "My Computer" groups that are listed are "Systems Tasks", "Other Places" and "Details". Is there a way to add directories of my choosing to the "Other Places" group?

Answer (score 5):

[This link](http://news.cnet.com/8301-13880_3-9884713-68.html) describes how to change the 5 slots for "Other places" (though you can't add new ones).

It seems that this is possible in the group policies parameters, or by using TweakUI:

[image: TweakUI - custom places bar]

Answer (score 2):

You can't actually add new items (even with TweakUI, I believe), but you can use TweakUI to point your 'Shared Folders' entry to a different folder.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like this behavior isn't supported by Windows Explorer. But I found [something](http://uneasysilence.com/how-to-osx-finder-style-for-windows-explorer/) that gets very close. It replaces the default sidebar with something that's customizable.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that 'TweakUI' can do this. Presumably it could be done manually in the registry too, but I don't know where.

Answer (score 0):

Without TweakUI, First go to the registry key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\comdlg32\PlacesBar` and then you will see five DWORD values, They are Places0 to Places4. Their values can be:

- Desktop - 0x00
- Network Neighborhood -  0x12
- Favorites - 0x06
- History - 0x22
- My Documents - 0x05
- My Pictures - 0x27
- My Music - 0x0D
- Recent Documents - 0x08
- My Computer - 0x11