# How to customize “Other Places” in “My Computer” view for WinXP

Tags: windows-xp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I add entries to Windows Explorer's “Other Places” sidebar?](https://superuser.com/questions/150574/how-do-i-add-entries-to-windows-explorers-other-places-sidebar)

When I open "My Computer" view, there are three sections in the left side - System Task, Other Places and Details, and there are "My Documents", "My Computer" and "My Network Places" in the "Other Places" section, can I add one more link in "Other Places" to point to a specific folder like E:\?

I tried to modify group policy, but it doesn't work.

Comment: I did some googling, found we can't customize this only changing some configuration. Found an article in vp:http://www.virtualplastic.net/html/wv_main.html#commontasks. Didn't have a practice to check if it's workable.